# Passing date in json file in KarateFramwork

Tags: json, date, parsing, format, karate

I have following function to get current date:

```
function() {
    var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
    var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd');
    var date = new java.util.Date();
    return sdf.format(date);
  }
```

And I'm passing the date to JSON file as follows:

```
* def currDate = getDate()
```

```
    JSON File:
    {
      "clientId": "ABC",
      "serviceLine": "DSS",
      "locationId": "VOL",
      "serviceType": "ADC",
      "attendanceDate": #(currDate),
      "saId": "123",
      "attendance": "PRESENT",
      "attendanceType": "ATTENDANCE"
    }
```

Json by default converts date into string for e.g. "20230210" (yyyyMMdd). This format is fine & as expected. But just I pass the variable currDate to JSON, it converts it into String with "", e.g., "20230210" but request should have date without quotes, i.e. just 20230210. Otherwise it gives error as Invalid Input.

How can I convert string to date format in JSON file?

Comment: okay. so your question is hard to understand. maybe you should tell us what you mean by "request payload requires in date format". there are hundreds of date formats, please be specific. or provide an example

Comment: format of date is fine & as expected. But just I pass the variable currDate to JSON, it converts it into String with "", for eg, "20230210" but request should have date without quotes, i.e. just 20230210. How can I convert string to date format in JSON file.

Comment: The JSON file given as example above is request. And I get 400 as response saying "invalid input"

Comment: so you just want to convert a string to a number ? that's easy :)

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s notoriously troublesome and long outdated. In Java: `LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)`. Don’t know how to fit it into Karate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your comments, looks like you are just trying to use the date format output as a number. That's easy, just do this:

```
* def currDate =  1 * getDate()
```

Also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#floats-and-integers